# sailsjs - process blueprint routes before config/routes

Tags: javascript, rest, express, routes, sails.js

I want to have a route like this in my config/routes.js

```
'*' : {
  controller: 'CustomRoutes',
  action: 'any',
  skipAssets:true
}
```

The `CustomRoutes` controller handles my custom routes. The `any` action simply returns a static html page.
This obviously doesn't work because it overrides my blueprint routes. Is there a way to have this route skip blueprint routes (like the `skipAssets`property) or could I set my blueprint routes to a higher priority than the routes in `config/routes.js` all together?
I would prefer to not use a prefix in `config/blueprints.js` because though I could use a regex expression to by-pass the blueprint routes, I would have to add the prefix all my client-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a way around not having a prefix.
Simply use the `skipRegex` property in the route to skip the prefix for the blueprints.
http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Routes/RouteTargetSyntax.html

```
'*' : {
  controller: 'CustomRoutes',
  action: 'any',
  skipAssets:true,
  skipRegex:/^\/api\/.*$/
}
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but your solution doesn't work for me. As if skipRegex doesn't do the Job because /api/ is not really prefixed to the blueprint routes. Do you know if something has changed concerning this topic since you gave your answer?